# How to read big file txt, and then make data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big txt file (52.375 kb, ln 86213, col 420).

```
name    | code  | school 
--------|-------|--------
steven  | 1234  | harvard
Michael | 98765 | MIT
```

I want to read it and make it as a data frame in pandas.

```
Df = statement_read(myfile.Txt)
```

I don't want to convert txt to csv manually. I want to read myfile.txt by python, so then I can process it by pandas.

Comment: Please make your question complete. Include the example of your input, expected output, and your code snippet.

Comment: I would look into [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: @ALollz can pd.read_csv read big file?

Comment: It can read anything your computer can fit into memory. And if the file is too large, it supports a [`chunksize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk) argument allowing your to process it in chunks.

Comment: Also, `pd.read_csv` can read any delimited file. The name is misleading, but for some reason the pandas devs decided to depricate `pd.read_table` in favor of having `pd.read_csv` handle all files.

Comment: @ALollz there's warning when i wrote pd.read_table " futurewarning : read_table is deprecated, use read_csv instead, passing sep=" \t". This id seperate from the ipykernel package so we cab avoid doing imporst until" thats the warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant how to process big files with pandas, then you need to use pandas chunk, for example for 10 gigabytes file, you can choose chunk size of 100 mb as an example, please note the chunk size is the number of rows you decided to read in each chunk.

```
import pandas as pd
for chunk in pd.read_csv('file.csv',chunksize=3):
    print(chunk[['name','code']])
```

#### update

let say you have sample file with billions of records

```
name,code,school

student1,c1,sch22
student2,c2,sch22
student3,c3,sch22
student4,c4,sch22
student5,c5,sch22
student6,c6,sch23
  .       .   .
  .       .   .
```

the above code shall fetch 3 rows in each patch as below

```
       name code school
0  student1   c1  sch22
1  student2   c2  sch22
2  student3   c3  sch22
       name code school
3  student4   c4  sch22
4  student5   c5  sch22
5  student6   c6  sch23
       name code school
6  student7   c7  sch24
7  student8   c8  sch25
8  student9   c9  sch26
```

Comment: Sorry sir this is the first use chunk, but it doesnt work. This is my code "for chunk in pd.read_csv("myfile.txt", sep = "    ", chunksize = 100"

Comment: @CharismaBathara please note, we just use chunk when the file is big enough so we cannot process it in the normal read_csv command.

Comment: Thanks sir, can i ask you? What is the meaning of chunksize?

Comment: @CharismaBathara chunk size is the number of rows that you want to read in each fetch (loop), as in our above example it is (3) rows

Comment: Ohh i see, btw why you use double [ ]?

Comment: for single column no need, but for multiple columns, you need to use list(array)  df[['col1','col2']] ...etc

Comment: @sir can i ask again? when i code

`df22 = pd.read_table("MonthlyFIRE_Feb_2017.txt")`

ther's warning:

\ipykernel_launcher.py:3: FutureWarning: read_table is deprecated, use read_csv instead, passing sep='\t'.
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until

what is that?

Comment: the warning is self-explained, to use read_csv instead or read_table, anyway it is not an error, you can ignore it by     import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)